# How does `Dates.value` function work in Julia?

Tags: datetime, julia, dates.jl

I learned that `Dates.value(Date)` returns an integer representation of that date.

```
using Dates

dt = Date(2020, 01, 01)

>>> println(Dates.value(dt))
737425
```

How does it go from 2020-01-01 to 737425?

Comment: Also, it would be nice to replace `>>>` with `julia>` in the question (there is actually a real effect, as the interpreter ignores `julia>` when pasting)

Answer (score 4):

The `value` is a field in this structure:

```
julia> dump(dt)
Date
  instant: Dates.UTInstant{Day}
    periods: Day
      value: Int64 737425
```

The `Dates.value` function extracts this field.

For the `Dates.Date` object `Date(1, 1, 1)` is associated with `value` equal to 1, and then consecutive days have `value` increasing by 1.

However, `Dates.value` is defined for other objects. E.g.:

```
julia> Dates.value(Time(1))
3600000000000

julia> Dates.value(Second(10))
10

julia> Dates.value(Minute(20))
20
```

The fact that `Dates.value` does not perform this computation is important as it ensures that the operation is fast.

If you want to see how this is calculated for `Date`, check the source code of `Dates.totaldays` function which calculates this using [Rata Die](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rata_Die) system:

```
# Convert y,m,d to # of Rata Die days
# Works by shifting the beginning of the year to March 1,
# so a leap day is the very last day of the year
const SHIFTEDMONTHDAYS = (306, 337, 0, 31, 61, 92, 122, 153, 184, 214, 245, 275)
function totaldays(y, m, d)
    # If we're in Jan/Feb, shift the given year back one
    z = m < 3 ? y - 1 : y
    mdays = SHIFTEDMONTHDAYS[m]
    # days + month_days + year_days
    return d + mdays + 365z + fld(z, 4) - fld(z, 100) + fld(z, 400) - 306
end
```

Comment: A better recommendation would be to direct to `Dates.days(dt)` function, which would work on other representations of the DateTime.

Comment: Fully agreed. `Dates.value` is a technical function.

Comment: Great! I removed my answer since this is undoubtedly the complete one.

Comment: In this case I have updated my answer, as your answer had useful information.

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński, great! 